What action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ yields a closed genus 3 surface
The closed, connected, orientable surface of genus 3 has universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Sigma_3$. As such, $\Sigma_3$ can be described as a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by some properly discontinuous action of $\pi_1(\Sigma_3)$.
My question: How can we describe this action?
The genus 1 case is easy: $\pi_1(\Sigma_1)=\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translations. Now, as a cell complex, $\Sigma_3$ can be described as a 12-gon. So perhaps the "translations" determined by a tiling of $\mathbb{R}^2$  by 12-gons might be what I'm looking for.

This can be done using Fuchsian groups acting on tilings of the hyperbolic plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane for details.

To properly visualize these actions, you should switch from Euclidean geometry to hyperbolic geometry. There is no "regular" tiling of the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$ by 12-gons, but there is indeed such a tiling of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$. If you choose that tiling carefully then you can get an action by actual translations of $\mathbb H^2$ determined by that tiling. Of course $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb H^2$ are homeomorphic, and so you use a homeomorphism to conjugate the action from $\mathbb H^2$ over to $\mathbb R^2$; but the latter action will look rather terribly distorted.
